# compiling 32-bit kernel on 64-bit linux os

Tags: linux-kernel

I compiled 32-bit kernel on a 64-bit ubuntu and installed it. But when I tried to boot from it , it gave me an error:

> Failed to execute /init
>
> Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found

And also the Caps Lock light kept on blinking.

But when I tried to boot from the original 64-bit kernel it booted successfully. Please tell me reason behind this and a solution to this.

Comment: Although you are "compiling", this sounds like a question more for an Ubuntu or Linux focused site rather than being a question directly related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much with just a kernel.  As soon as the kernel is done booting, it calls an external process (called `init`) which begins starting other services and processes from user space, in order to arrive at a functional system.  This includes mounting filesystems, configuring some hot-pluggable devices, launching network services, and, of course, providing a login screen.

A 64-bit operating system can run both 64-bit and 32-bit binaries.  A 32-bit operating system can only run 32-bit binaries.  And it appears that your system (including `init`) is a 64-bit system.  Therefore, your 32-bit kernel will be unable to do anything after booting, since all the necessary system utilities are compiled in 64-bit mode.

I can't think of any reason one would want to "downgrade" to a 32-bit kernel on a 64-bit distribution, even if it were possible.